# What's recommended size for HTML(page) response

Tags: seo, html, page-size

Consider following example:

1. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html
2. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html

1 is whole document in single html with large html response.
2 is separate each title/section id different url(file).

Question is which one is recommended for performance/seo

Any HTML size recommended by Google or other seo optimization rules?

Note: it's about HTML size **not** assets like css,js,image and etc...

Comment: Related: [What is the maximum size of an HTML file that Google will crawl through?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47233/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-an-html-file-that-google-will-crawl-through)